# map_location=torch.device('cpu') does not solve 'RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device'

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

The complete error is:

```
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

I am using torch 1.10.1, and with the following model:

```
encoder = Encoder_SPEC2MIDI(config['input']['margin_b'],
                        config['input']['num_frame'],
                        config['feature']['n_bins'],
                        args.cnn_channel,
                        args.cnn_kernel,
                        args.hid_dim,
                        args.enc_layer,
                        args.enc_head,
                        args.pf_dim,
                        args.dropout,
                        self.device)

decoder = Decoder_SPEC2MIDI(config['input']['num_frame'],
                            config['feature']['n_bins'],
                            config['midi']['num_note'],
                            config['midi']['num_velocity'],
                            args.hid_dim,
                            args.dec_layer,
                            args.dec_head,
                            args.pf_dim,
                            args.dropout,
                            self.device)

model = Model_SPEC2MIDI(encoder, decoder)
model = model.to(self.device)

if model_path == None:
    self.model = None
else:
    self.model = load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
    with open(model_path, 'rb') as f:
        #self.model = pickle.load(f)
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(args.model_best_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
    self.model = model
    #self.model = self.model.to(self.device)
    self.model.eval()
```

The line

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(args.model_best_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
```

has been inserted following the upvoted comments here on stackoverflow, but does not solve the problem. The output confirms the model is running on the 'cpu'.

Previously, I was able to load the model without any issue using `pickle.load()` (now commented). After reinstalling torch by mistake, and make sure I was using the same version as before, 1.10.1, I started getting this error message out of the blue.